# How can I recover from a CoreNLP Timeout, and continue to process requests?

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I started my Standford NLP server (CoreNLP **v 3.91**, `stanford-corenlp-full-2018-02-27.zip`) on Ubuntu 16.04 with this command:

> java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000

And after some time, if I throw too large of a sentence at it, it blows up.

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer$CoreNLPHandler.handle (StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:866)

[pool-1-thread-6] INFO CoreNLP - [/127.0.0.1:34048] API call w/annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,parse,depparse
But if you ask any feminist directly (and I have, one of my best friends is a woman's studies major and we have had MANY heated passionate arguments; i've spoken to her friends too), they will fully say that modern feminism is about having the choice, and while they completely disagree with women who take this choice, it is still their choice to make.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer$CoreNLPHandler.handle(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:866)
        at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
        at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
        at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
        at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
        at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
        at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[Thread-0] INFO CoreNLP - CoreNLP Server is shutting down.
```

Unfortunately this kills my server. I have my python script catch the exception caused by the server timeout, but how can I pass it, and continue using the server. I am currently using an `eval()` to restart the server using the above command.

## Is there a better way skip over these crashes?

EDIT: Here is an example where CoreNLP v 3.91 fails when I throw too large of a sentence at it:
[image: Timeout Exception]
Notice how a very long sentence will cause the timeout exception, and it crashes the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should try getting the latest code.  When I submit a very long sentence to the server, I get the timeout exception, but it doesn't crash the server.

Latest code can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP  Last stable release (3.9.1) here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/

You can also try setting "parse.maxlen = 100" (or something smaller) to prevent annotating really long sentences.  Other annotators have options for not processing very long sentences, which is usually the main culprit.

Comment: Thank you, after investigating I found out that I am running the latest version. 3.9.1 `stanford-corenlp-full-2018-02-27.zip`. I have updated my question above. Are there any other options I could try? I just found out that I'm running openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)